# AB modeling in anylogic (statechart)

Tags: simulation, anylogic, agent-based-modeling, statechart

I have a problem where the state of one agent depends on the states of its components. Like I have a machine which consists of 10 different components. each one has its own state chart( the states could be; Operating,failed, under manitenance...etc).  So the machine will fail if at least one component fails and it will be up if all of them is operating. What I did is to create the 10 agents and create thier statecharts( please note that each component has different failure rate, repair time..etc that is why i seperate them) and i created one agent for the machine with its statechart(that is dependent on the 10 statecharts),  I am stuck here, I could not find way to get the state of the machine based on its components' states. 
It should be AB modeling 
Thanks alot

Comment: Did you create another agent (machine)  with its own statechart? How are you using this agents?
Can you present more information on the system? Some images would also be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I created one agent(machine) with its own statechart. The machine has 10 components each has different failure rate, sparepart inventory, delivery time for its spares,replacing time.The statecharts of the 10 components are the same but the inputs are different for example (operating-failed-undermaintenance) the action from operating to failed is triggered by failure rate (and this rate is different from on comp. to another).the machine has two states operating when the 10 comps. are working or failed when one or more comp are in failed or under maintenance states.i am new i cant add image

Comment: I understand Samar. It's harder to help you without further information but I believe you would greatly benefit from following this course by nathaniel osgood from mit http://www.anylogic.com/mit-course-on-abm
He goes into many aspects of AB modeling

Comment: https://www.cs.usask.ca/faculty/ndo885/Classes/MIT15879/LectureSlides/Lecture%208%20--%20Discrete%20Inter-agent%20Dynamics,%20Sending%20&%20Receiving%20Messages.pdf This particular lecture might be of greater use. Is on inter-agent relations. Following the previous link you can also access the video/audio

Comment: You're welcome. If you find out how to solve your specific problem, post an answer to your own post so that someone might use it in the future when facing a similar issue ;)

Comment: For sure I will do